# Node.js Connecting to redis cluster

Tags: node.js, redis, redis-cluster

There are tons of examples and resources for connecting to a redis "server" but not to a redis "cluster".

What I currently have is:

```
const redis = require("redis"); 
const client = redis.createClient({
 port      : 6379,               // replace with your port
 host      : '10.0.0.100',        // replace with your hostanme or IP address
 password  : 'Notforyou',    // replace with your password
 // optional, if using SSL
 // use `fs.readFile[Sync]` or another method to bring these values in
 tls       : {
   key  : stringValueOfKeyFile,  
   cert : stringValueOfCertFile,
   ca   : [ stringValueOfCaCertFile ]
 }
});
```

But this is for a single redis server not a cluster. How would I go about connecting to my cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this library [ioredis](https://github.com/luin/ioredis#cluster)

I think that this will help you with your issue.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out and get back to you!

Comment: That is awesome!

Comment: I am glad that this helped you :)

Comment: if your up for it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61690116/multiple-config-in-json-for-node-js

Answer (score 1):

The Readme tab in [redis npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis) has this link([Clustering Guide](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/HEAD/docs/clustering.md)) explaining how to connect to redis cluster with node under heading 'Clustering'. It's very simple, create a cluster instead of creating client and configure the nodes url as given in this [example](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/HEAD/docs/clustering.md#basic-example)